# Will an Ubuntu install with Nvidia drivers boot properly on a system with an AMD GPU?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, amd-graphics

So, I love having an external HDD with Ubuntu on it and bring able to boot it on any computer and be right at home in Linux with all my files and programs.

Now here's my question: if I install the Nvidia drivers, will it only boot properly on a system with an Nvidia GPU, or will it still work just fine on systems with an Intel or AMD GPU?

Normally I would just try it and see what happens, but I would prefer not to screw up my drive and have to spend a few hours fixing it. (I've already nuked one Ubuntu install beyond repair when messing with the Nvidia drivers about a year ago)

Comment: messing with nvidia driver never destroys an ubuntu beyond repair. But no it won't work, you'd need to disable it afterwards in the configurations or it won't work.

Comment: @Ziazis Oh trust me, I nuked it pretty well. I couldn't get the X server to start, and all attempts to reinstall failed due to dependencies.... It was a mess.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning before a new attempt? `sudo apt purge nvidia*`. That should be all you need in the new system in the event it fails to load X. Then you may need `nomodeset` and whether or not the AMD will automatically work with `radeon` or `amdgpu`, or Intel with its drivers, it's another story. Other than that I have to agree with @Ziazis

Comment: @MichaelBay I spent hours trying to repair that system. I even uninstalled and reinstalled the the X server, and yes I purged the Nvidia drivers, all to no avail. In any case, we're beating a dead horse since that install has been histroy for a year :P